# Is there a way to display the vertex weight values for each vertex in the viewport while weightpainting a vertex group on the viewport?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I've always found it difficult to tell quite accurately enough the weight of the vertex while weightpainting, I'm aware the colors are there to indicate it but i've found it hard to tell quite accurately what amount they're at with them often (does a weightpaint gradient guide image exist on that topic?) So I was wondering if there's an option that allows you to see the numbers for each vertex's weight value, similar to something like displaying the bone names of bones on the viewport (as seen on the second image).
[image]

[image]

Comment: No, you can't ... You can only see weight of selected vertex in 3dView Properties side panel.

Comment: yes you can...with AN ;)

Answer (score 2):

you could use animation nodes (free add-on, worth learning it, it is extremely powerful) - with this very simple node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

update:

i improved my node tree, so that the numbers are now always rotating to the viewport:

[image]

script:

```
import bpy

def find_area():
    try:
        for a in bpy.data.window_managers[0].windows[0].screen.areas:
            if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
                return a
        return None
    except:
        return None

area = find_area()

if area is None:
    print("area not find")
else:
    
    r3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
    
q = r3d.view_rotation
```

node tree:

[image]

Comment: That does seem pretty helpful, I'll try to give it a shot. Hopefully it's not too hard to learn or setup the nodes like that.

Comment: I've tried setting it up now, however I can't seem to get it to work right (this is how it looks https://imgur.com/a/MDa60gC). Would it be possible for you to send me your scene/setup so I could see closer what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just play around with the scale in the object transform output, so that your numbers are smaller. Also i would check "in front" for the original text so you can see all numbers. of course the rotation depends on your setup. so you have to play with that as well so that you can read the numbers.